# Rails generators for subscription and payment processing services?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I've been thinking about making a generator for managing subscriptions with options for a couple different payment processing services, it is something that I would use. Are there any existing examples of this, or any thoughts on a generator. I thought it might work like the scaffold function, similar to the authentication function in nifty-generators.

EDIT: Also, It seems that there should be a lot of security concerns when implementing payment processing, having a consistent and common way to generate this would let me make sure best practices and security are followed the same in all my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the pain you'll experience when you start to navigate the byzantine requirements of PCI compliance, I think "best practices" in this area is **not to handle payment processing in the first place.**

At least, not within your application.

[Stripe](https://stripe.com) is an online payment processor geared toward developers. It's a breeze to accept credit card payments through their API, and it offloads responsibility (and liability) for PCI regulation issues to someone else. Which is a Good Thing.

There's even a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) all about using Stripe to handle payments, and the [stripe-rails gem](https://github.com/mhs/stripe-rails) will bootstrap the process for you.

Oh, and Stripe handles periodic billing (for subscriptions) for you.

Before you head down this road, I highly recommend taking a look at available technologies you might leverage. Although the code for payment processing is often fairly straightforward, the liability issues are massive.

P.S. I don't work for Stripe or anything. I just think their product/service is excellent, and a good match for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

For the payment part have a look at [ActiveMerchant](http://activemerchant.org/). If there is a gem for subscriptions you can find at [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/).

If it doesn't exist yet, it would really be a good idea to write one. I have seen several sites that could have used one. Though this may become a more complicated task than a simple generator. To handle subscriptions (especially in combination with payments) you would need a process (like cron job) that checks subscriptions in regular intervals and generates payments or mails requests for renewals (and several more tasks, depending on usage scenario)

Comment: I'd like to scaffold Mailers etc. to have a framework in place for those mail requests and such

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the open source example application for a **[Rails Membership Site with Stripe](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-stripe-membership-saas/)** or **[Rails Membership Site with Recurly](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-recurly-subscription-saas/)** from the [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.com/) project. Both are generated by the  [Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) tool. You could use the [rails_apps_composer gem](http://railsapps.github.com/rails_apps_composer/) to create application templates to handle other billing services (but Stripe and Recurly may be sufficient).